# Almacenar estructuras en un fichero binario

Tags: array, c, archivo, estructuras-de-datos, binario

Estoy programando  en C un programa en el que necesito almacenar estructuras "Marca" en un fichero binario para que queden registradas. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo varios problemas y no se cuál es la forma mas adecuada de almacenarlos.

Exactamente quiero ir añadiendo una Marca nueva a las ya almacenadas en el fichero, y no se si sería más adecuado guardar un array de Marcas en el fichero y cada vez que se vaya a incluir una nueva sacar el array, meter el nuevo Usuario en el array, y volver a meterlo el array en el fichero para sobrescribir el anterior.

Otra forma seria ir añadiéndolos sin ningún array, pero creo que se necesitaría que cada Usuario estuviese en una línea distinta para que se pudiese distinguir cuando empieza un nuevo array.

En el siguiente código, muestro el proceso de registro de la marca m en la función registroMarca() (funciona correctamente), y abajo el registro en el fichero binario con la forma del array, pero hay algún problema y no funciona correctamente.

```
void registroMarca(Marca *m) {
    printf("\n\n-------Registrar marca--------\n\n");


    //REGISTRO DE LA MARCA
    char str[MAX_LINE];
    int id;

    printf("ID: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    sscanf(str, "%i", &id);
    clearIfNeeded(str, MAX_LINE);

    m->id = id;

    printf("Nombre de la marca:");
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    char *str_fmt = malloc(MAX_LINE * sizeof(char));
    sscanf(str, "%s", str_fmt);
    m->nombre = malloc((strlen(str_fmt) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(m->nombre, str_fmt);
    free(str_fmt);

    printf("Contraseña:");
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(str, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    char *str_fmt2 = malloc(MAX_LINE * sizeof(char));
    sscanf(str, "%s", str_fmt2);
    m->contrasena = malloc((strlen(str_fmt2) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(m->contrasena, str_fmt2);
    free(str_fmt2);

    //GUARDAR EN EL FICHERO

    FILE *file2;
    file2 = fopen("marcas.bin", "w");
    int num;
    Marca  *marcas;

    if (file2 == NULL){
        printf("Error al abrir el fichero de marcas\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Para saber si el fichero esta vacio 
    fseek(file2, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int empty = ftell() == 0L;

    if(empty == 0){  //si está vacio --> crear el array y meter la marca actual

        Marca *arrayMarcas;
        arrayMarcas = malloc(sizeof(m));
        *arrayMarcas = *m;
        fputc(1, file2);
        fwrite(arrayMarcas, sizeof(arrayMarcas), 1, file2);
        fclose(file2);

    } else{ //si no esta vacio --> sacar el array de marcas existentes, añadir la nueva Marca al final del array, y volver a meter el array en el fichero

        FILE *file3;
        file3 = fopen("marcas.bin", "r+");
        fputc(1, file3);
        num = fgetc(file3);
        marcas = (Marca*)malloc((num * sizeof(Marca)) + sizeof(Marca));
        fread(marcas, sizeof(Marca), num, file3);

        marcas[num] = *m;

        fputc(1, file3);
        fwrite(marcas, sizeof(marcas), 1, file3);
        fclose(file3);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Exactamente quiero ir añadiendo una Marca nueva a las ya almacenadas en el fichero

Pues ya empezamos mal. Tal y como abres el archivo, estás eliminando su contenido y dejándolo vacío:

```
file2 = fopen("marcas.bin", "w");
```

Tal y como reza la [documentación](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm):

- **"w"**: Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file.

Es decir:

- **"w"**: Crea un archivo vacío para escritura. Si ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre, su contenido se borrará y el archivo se considerará como un nuevo archivo vacío.

Para concatenar contenido deberías abrir el archivo así:

```
file2 = fopen("marcas.bin", "a");
```

Como ves, es posible abrir un archivo para añadir contenido al ya existente, luego no hace falta leer todo el array para volver a escribirlo. Eso solo es necesario si quieres eliminar un registro sin dejar huecos en el archivo.

tu código podría resumirse en:

```
// Se abre el archivo
FILE * file = fopen("marcas.bin", "a");

// Se guardan las nuevas marcas
fwrite(m, num * sizeof(Marca), file);

// Se cierra el archivo
fclose(file);
```